# Mongoose/Typescript - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when catch is present

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I'm not sure why I'm seeing this UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.  In this code, 'id' is a Mongoose Index, and I am testing inserting a duplicate ID which should be handled properly.

```
router.post('/create/:id', jsonParser, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let { id } = req.params;
    if (!req.body) {
        return res.sendStatus(400)
    }

    // @TODO add validation on JSON
    let promise = Requirement.create({id: id, data: req.body.data, deleted: false});

    promise.then((requirement) => {
        return res.json(requirement);
    });

    promise.catch((reason) => {
        let err = {'error': reason};
        return res.json(err);
    });
});
```

In fact, the following JSON is returned, so I know my rejection handler is executing:

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "MongoError",
        "message": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: rex.requirements index: id_1 dup key: { : \"REQ001\" }",
        "driver": true,
        "index": 0,
        "code": 11000,
        "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: rex.requirements index: id_1 dup key: { : \"REQ001\" }"
    }
}
```

The exact warnings I'm seeing are the following:

```
(node:11408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: rex.requirements index: id_1 dup key: { : "REQ001" }
(node:11408) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`catch` catches an error from `promise` but not `promise.then(...)`. If an error is thrown inside `then`, this would result in unhandled rejection. Even if it's not thrown but is propagated from `promise`, it is considered uncaught in this promise.

It should be:

```
promise
.then((requirement) => {
    return res.json(requirement);
})
.catch((reason) => {
    let err = {'error': reason};
    return res.json(err);
});
```

Comment: Interesting, so here, both exceptions from the promise and the then are handled by the catch?

Comment: Yes. If they should be handled separately then consider adding another `catch` before `then`. But I guess in your case they can be handled with single `catch`.

Answer (score 1):

You basically did

```
var a = promise.then(…);
var b = promise.catch(…);
```

creating a branch in the chain. If `promise` is getting rejected now, the `catch` callback will be called and `b` will be a fulfilled promise just fine, but the `a` promise is getting rejected too and nobody handles that.

Instead, you should use both arguments of `then` and write

```
Requirement.create({id: id, data: req.body.data, deleted: false})
.then(requirement => {
    res.json(requirement);
}, reason => {
    let err = {'error': reason};
    res.json(err);
});
```