# How is PromiseRejectionEvent triggered?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am confused about the following problem：

defined `onunhandledrejection`

```
window.onunhandledrejection = event =>{
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('catch unhandlerejection', event)
}
```

and two test functions

```
function test1() {
    const rejectedP = Promise.reject('-');
    rejectedP.finally();
    return rejectedP;
}

async function test2() {
    const rejectedP = Promise.reject('-');
    rejectedP.finally();
    return rejectedP;
}
```

when i called `test1`,only caught one `onunhandledrejection`,but when i called `test2`,i caught two.

What is the difference between `test1` and `test2`?

Comment: test2 is ```async``` function.

Comment: `.finally()` expects you to pass it a callback, otherwise no point in calling it, so it's unclear what you think you're doing with `rejectedP.finally();`.

Comment: @TienDuong, can you explain in more details what is it different from `async` function to return promise?

Comment: `async` function always returns a Promise and you explicitly returned `rejectedP`. Why bother using `async` without `await`?

Comment: The interesting part is that the duplicated event only occurs with the added `.finally()` even though this seems like it is not doing anything at first. So yeah, it would interesting to know what is happening here behind the scenes in combination with async.

Comment: Basically [you are creating two independent promises that are both rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50546622/1048572).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test2` being marked `async` does wrap your return value in a new promise:

```
function test2() { // de-async-ified
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const rejectedP = Promise.reject('-');
        rejectedP.finally();
        resolve(rejectedP);
    });
}
```

If we do compare the calls

```
const result1 = test1();
const result2 = test2();
```

by expanding them to

```
const rejectedP = Promise.reject('-');
const finallyP = rejectedP.finally();
const result1 = rejectedP;

const result2 = new Promise(resolve => {
    const rejectedP = Promise.reject('-');
    const finallyP = rejectedP.finally();
    resolve(rejectedP);
});
```

we can see that the first snippet creates two promises (`result1` and `rejectedP` being the same) while the second snippet creates three promises. All of these promises are rejected, but the `rejectedP` rejection is handled by the callbacks attached to it, both through `….finally()` and `resolve(…)` (which internally does `….then(resolve, reject)`).

`finallyP` is the promise whose rejection is not handled in the both examples. In the second example, `result2` is a promise distinct from `rejectedP` that is also not handled, causing the second event.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how to understand "the rejectedP rejection is handled by the callbacks attached to it" ?

Comment: @huitingChen The promise `rejectedP` is marked as "handled" because there are handler callbacks attached to it (through `finally` and `then`) that would either handle the rejection or at least propagate it down the chain. So even while `rejectedP` is rejected, no `unhandledrejection` event is triggered for it - it's not *unhandled*.

Answer (score 0):

Since test2 is an async function, its result is wrapped in a `Promise`.

[JavaScript Async Return Value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value)